# SharePoint Subsite data Import into Power BI

Tags: sharepoint, powerbi, powerbi-desktop

How to SharePoint Site Content in Subsite list Data Import into Power BI.
And How  to Insert Many difference Subsite List data insert into Power BI

Example : [image]

Answer (score 0):

There's no difference between a SharePoint Site and a Subsite. To import data in PowerQuery you just have to enter the root URL of the subsite instead.